# how to merge two Word2Vec File

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

I created my model using Word2Vec.
But the results were not good.
So I want to add a word.
The code I created the first time
Creation is possible, but can not be added.
Please tell me how can add.

createModel.py

```
token = loadCsv("test_data")
embeddingmodel = []
for i in range(len(token)):
temp_embeddingmodel = []
for k in range(len(token[i][0])):
    temp_embeddingmodel.append(token[i][0][k])
embeddingmodel.append(temp_embeddingmodel)

embedding = Word2Vec(embeddingmodel, size=300, window=5, min_count=3, iter=100, sg=1,workers=4, max_vocab_size = 360000000)
embedding.save('post.embedding')
```

loadWord2Vec.py

```
tokens = W2V.tokenize(sentence)
embedding = Convert2Vec('Data/post.embedding', tokens)
zero_pad = W2V.Zero_padding(embedding, Batch_size, Maxseq_length, Vector_size)
```

Tell me how to add or merge the results of Word2Vec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to merge two `Word2Vec` models.

Only word-vectors that were trained together are "in the same space" and thus comparable.

The best policy would be to combine the two training corpuses of texts, and train a new model on the combined data, thus obtaining word-vectors for all words from the same training session.